# Network bandwidth aggregation

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, network-interface, tcp, iproute

Lets say I have access to two different networks: A and B. My device has two different network interfaces N1 and N2.

A has a bandwidth of 5 mbps
B has a bandwidth of 3 mbps

I want to combine these two Networks to get a total bandwidth of: 8 Mbps. The way I was thinking of doing it as follows:

I use the two network Interfaces(N1, N2) to connect to the networks A, B. Lets say I have hundred packets to send. I send 50 packets using network A and 50 using network B. I send these packets to a personal server where packets coming from network A and B are combined and are sent to the intended location.

In order to do all this I think I will have to get all traffic from the network layer and send it to different interfaces.

Assuming everything I just mentioned is doable, I want to know how can I intercept the packets coming from the internet layer so that I can implement the above logic and channel the traffic to different interfaces.

Comment: You must explain the layout. Are these network "layer 2" or "layer 3" if layer 3, how are they routed, are you in control of the routing. Are you simply describing a multi-homed access to Internet (where you don't have much control)? etc. Please give an example with interfaces and IP addresses where relevant, including the client, the intermediate server and the target. Be sure to tell if some addresses are private or public.